# Easiest way to animate a collection of shapes in processing?

Tags: animation, processing

I have been working on learning processing and now feel fairly comfortable drawing shapes and editing color etc. I have tried to take the step towards animating one of my prior works, but I just seem to keep running into dead ends or I can't get the unit to move cohesively. Essentially I am trying to move this entire guitar around the screen in any manner whatsoever as long as it stays intact. If you have a recommendation I would greatly appreciate it!

Current code is as follows:

```
void setup() {

size(600,600);

smooth();

noLoop();

}

void draw() {   
  //pegs
  strokeJoin(SQUARE);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(530,105,20,20);
  rect(565,70,20,20);
  rect(473,50,20,20);
  rect(505,18,20,20);

  //neck and head
  strokeWeight(60);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  stroke(165,42,42);
  line(490,110,560,40);
  fill(255,255,255);
  strokeWeight(45);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  line(300,295,500,105);



  //guitar body
  noStroke();
  fill(222,184,135);
  ellipse(200,400,200,200);
  ellipse(280,310,150,150);

  //Sound Hole
  fill(255,140,0);
  ellipse(235,360,110,110);  
  fill(0,0,0);
  ellipse(235,360,100,100);

  //strings
  stroke(255,255,255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  line(170,390,540,40);
  line(180,400,550,45);
  line(195,410,560,50);
  line(207,420,570,55);

 //string attatchment bottom
 strokeWeight(6);
 strokeCap(SQUARE);
 stroke(165,42,42);
 line(210,425,170,385);


}
```

Comment: Add a language tag to your question.

Comment: The language is processing in case anyone else cannot see the tag.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't realise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will animate your guitar so that it will move along the positive x-axis. This is just an example to give you an idea how "animation" really works:

```
// this will be used to move the guitar along x

int alongX = 0;

void setup() {

  background(128);

  size(600, 600);

  smooth();

  //noLoop();
}

void draw() { 
  background(128);  
  //pegs
  strokeJoin(SQUARE);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(530+alongX, 105, 20, 20);
  rect(565+alongX, 70, 20, 20);
  rect(473+alongX, 50, 20, 20);
  rect(505+alongX, 18, 20, 20);

  //neck and head
  strokeWeight(60);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  stroke(165, 42, 42);
  line(490+alongX, 110, 560+alongX, 40);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  strokeWeight(45);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  strokeJoin(ROUND);
  line(300+alongX, 295, 500+alongX, 105);



  //guitar body
  noStroke();
  fill(222, 184, 135);
  ellipse(200+alongX, 400, 200, 200);
  ellipse(280+alongX, 310, 150, 150);

  //Sound Hole
  fill(255, 140, 0);
  ellipse(235+alongX, 360, 110, 110);  
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  ellipse(235+alongX, 360, 100, 100);

  //strings
  stroke(255, 255, 255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  line(170+alongX, 390, 540+alongX, 40);
  line(180+alongX, 400, 550+alongX, 45);
  line(195+alongX, 410, 560+alongX, 50);
  line(207+alongX, 420, 570+alongX, 55);

  //string attatchment bottom
  strokeWeight(6);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  stroke(165, 42, 42);
  line(210+alongX, 425, 170+alongX, 385);

  // incrementing alongX to move it along +x, decrement it to move it along -x
  alongX++;
}
```

The idea is very simple. Animation is basically an illusion of movement. Objects appear such that they're moving but the effect is achieved very simply by drawing and redrawing (at a certain speed: `frameRate`) the objects on the screen in different locations in such a way that they appear to the viewer as though they're moving when in reality they're not.

For this effect to be *effective*, you have to have certain things in your sketch (or any other animation package):

- You need to have variables that control the position of the object so
  when you want to *move* the object, you can easily change the values
  of the variables controlling the position in such a way that it would
  give the illusion of movement.
- You also, in this case, need to keep redrawing the background. That
  is why I added the `background(128);` line in your `draw()` method.
  If you comment that line out, you will see that the effect is
  different and the guitar leaves a trail (maybe that's what you
  want...a trail that later fades away? Its up to you!).
- Another thing you need to consider in your sketch is that while
  `rect`s and `ellipse`s only need to have one variable changed in
  order for them to move from left to right (in the case of this
  sketch), `line`s need to have both `x` values manipulated by your
  variable.
- `noLoop()` in `setup()` is specifically designed so you can stop
  `draw()` from its `infinite loop` or `game loop` but stopping
  `draw()` means no animation effects. You can have `noLoop()`, for
  example, to stop the animation upon pressing a key but then you'd
  also want to provide `loop()` to get the animation going upon
  pressing a key. These are some things and decisions for you to think
  about and play with.
- Finally, I just changed your sketch a little to show you how
  animation may work. You can add a ton of things to it to make it
  awesome.

PS: Cool guitar!

**UPDATE**

After getting comfortable with the idea of moving objects around, I would look at vectors and how they can be used to set the direction, and velocity of objects. Take a look at [PVector](http://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) in Processing. [This tutorial](http://processing.org/tutorials/pvector/) would be sufficient to get you going with PVectors. But I would do this on objects. For example, a full `Guitar` object. Not on individual `line`s and `rect`s.